# Collection object of an entity fetches value after session close

Tags: spring-4, hibernate-4.x

I have an entity having OneToMany relationship. After fetching the parent entity by below way:

User has many educational degrees.

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
-----------at interface level--------------

public User getUser(int userid){
...
return user;
}

Now when trying to get the child collection(educational degree) , due to session is closed failed to lazily initialize a collection of role exception is occuring.

Please explain how collection object get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, we should use `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` to load the collection of entities.